# Integrating vue-chartjs(version from 2.8.7 to 3.2.1)?

Tags: vue.js, vue-chartjs

I have integrated the npm vuecharts(version-2.8.7) in my project , now i upgraded the version to 3.2.1, when i run the project the following errors occurs, what will be the solution for it?

RevenueMiniChart.js?6508:3 Uncaught TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_vue_chartjs**.b.Bar.extend is not a function

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47080720/1640606

Answer (score 0):

`vue-chartjs` follows semver. So the "breaking" release is the v 3.0.0
Some things how you create your components have changed.

Just check out the Release Notes: https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/releases/tag/v3.0.0

There is a migration guide. It is super easy and you should be done in a few mins.